# Use Weierstrass to show $f(x)=0$

Tags: analysis

I was reviewing for a test and I'm not sure how to approach this problem:

Suppose $f$ is a function continuous on $[0,1]$ with
$$\int_0^1x^nf(x)dx=0$$
for all **even** integers $n\geq0$. Then $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

Is this true? And if so, how can it be proved? I believe that the Weierstrass approximation can be used but I'm not sure how to apply it exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(x)=\sqrt x f(\sqrt x)$. Then $\int_0^{1} g(x) x^{n}\, dx =2\int_0^{1} f(y)y^{2n+2}\, dy=0$ for all $n \geq 0$. Hence $g(x)=0$ for all $x$ which implies $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$, then it can be extended to an even continuous function $\tilde f(x)$ on $[-1, 1]$ by
\begin{align}
\tilde f(x) =
\begin{cases}
f(x) & \text{ if } 0\leq x\leq 1,\\
f(-x) & \text{ if } -1 \leq x <0
\end{cases}.
\end{align}
Note that since
\begin{align}
\int^1_0 f(x)x^{2k}\ dx = 0
\end{align}
for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then 
\begin{align}
\int^1_{-1} \tilde f(x) x^{2k}\ dx = \int^1_0 f(x)x^{2k}\ dx+\int^0_{-1} f(-x)x^{2k}\ dx = 0.
\end{align}

Hence $\tilde f$ is an even function which is orthogonal to $x^{2k}$ for any $k$. In particular, $\tilde f$ is orthogonal to all the even Legendre polynomials. However, since even functions are generated by the even Legendre polynomials on $[-1, 1]$, then $\tilde f$ must be zero.